# ios - Eureka ActionSheetRow options text collapsing if too long

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I'm using Eureka (v1.5.1) to create a form with several ActionSheetRow fields.
The problem is that we have very long strings to use as options in the presented UIAlertController & they appear collapsed & with "..." in the middle.
For the same reason, options with short text appears with bigger font than the ones with long text (and this seems like an answer suggestion :) )

Is there a way to make options text multiline?
Any idea?

Thanks!

[image: This is how it appears]

Answer (score 1):

i dont know what kind of library u r using, but u can just use \n for multiline and set your linebreakmode, number of lines

```
let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Class", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
let course1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Computer Science(1st year) \n Digital Electronics", style: .default)
let course2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Computer Science(2nd year) \n Digital Electronics", style: .default)
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
optionMenu.addAction(course1)
optionMenu.addAction(course2)
optionMenu.addAction(cancel)
self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

// Setting up the number of lines and doing a word wrapping        
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:[UIAlertController.self]).numberOfLines = 2
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:[UIAlertController.self]).lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:[UIAlertController.self]).numberOfLines = 0
```